# Combine multiple dataframes into one that sums their values according to the index

Tags: python, pandas, sum

I have several pandas dataframes, each with one column of ints in them, and I would like to create a new dataframe with the sum of their values at each index. Their indexes will have some overlapping entries and these are the indecies whose values I want to add together. If an index is found in only one dataframe I want the new dataframe (or series) to include that index and just use that one value as its value. This seems straight-forward but I can't figure it out and the documentation seems to focus on joining dataframes more so than combining their values.
Basically, given two dataframes that look like this:

```
>>> df1
   0
a  3
b  7
d  2
>>> df2
    0
c  11
d  19
```

And I'd like to have the final output look like this:

```
>>> df3
    0
a   3
b   7
c  11
d  21
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Always check the docs...that's a pretty straightforward problem.  http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.add.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simplest answer, if you're only adding two dataframes:

```
# fill_value parameter specifies how to treat missing rows, since you can't add NaN (i.e. add 0)
df3 = df1.add(df2, fill_value=0)

df3
Out[18]: 
   0
a  3
b  7
c  13
d  19
```

However, if you want to add more than two, the easiest and fastest way is more like this:

```
import pandas as pd

# initialize example inputs
df1 = pd.DataFrame([3, 7, 2], index=['a', 'b', 'c'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame([11, 19], index=['c', 'd'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame([3, 7, 11, 21], index=['a', 'b', 'c', 'd'])

# when concatenating with axis=1, columns are added side by side. Rows are matched with other rows having the same index.
aggregate_df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)

# sum across columns (axis=1).  Convert resulting Series to DataFrame
df4 = aggregate_df.sum(axis=1).to_frame()

df4
Out[11]: 
    0
a   6
b  14
c  24
d  40
dtype: float64
```